Problem with downloading data from OECD using R
I have been trying to dowload datasets from the OECD using R.
library(OECD)

search_dataset("transport")


Error in read_xml.response(httr::GET(url, ...)) : Not Found (HTTP 404).
and

get_datasets()


Error in read_xml.response(httr::GET(url, ...)) : Not Found (HTTP 404).

Only this command works when I specify the particular data set that I want to download, e.g. get_dataset(dataset = "ITF_GOODS_TRANSPORT")
I tried to use various ways of installation of the OECD package, such as
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/expersso/OECD")

library(devtools)
 devtools::install_version("OECD", version = "0.2.4", repos = "https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/")

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("jsicherman/GemmAPI")


As suggested by this GitHub issue, it looks like the search_dataset() method is no longer supported. This seems to be confirmed by the devs stating the best way to use the package is to use the OECD Data Explorer to both browse available datasets and filter specific datasets. The only reference to search_dataset() I could find is for OECD 0.2.0 from 2019.

It seems that the OECD search_datasets() and get_datasets() functions are disabled, you can search for the data you want on OECD Data Explorer, click on "Developer API", and use the generated URL to f t https://www.oecd.org/en/data/insights/data-explainers/2024/09/api.html
